# In memcpy how to handle memory overflow?

Tags: c, memcpy

```
int main ()
{
    char *destination;
    char source[10] = "jigarpatel";
    destination = (char*) malloc(5);
    memcpy(destination, source, 10);
    printf("%s and size is %d", destination, strlen(destination));
    free(destination);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 jigarpatel and size is 10
```

Question:

Here I have allocated just 5 bytes to destination, but the destination length is 10, why is this?

Where are the other bytes stored?

Is it safe in embedded system? Any chances of a crash or a segmentation fault?

How can I detect this type of mistake?

**Another Question** :

see i am writing one library where user asks for needed memory and library says allocate 10 bytes & then user malloc 10 bytes & pass its pointer to library. now library store some data there...now see if library said to allocate 10 bytes but user has allocated only 5 bytes & give that pointer to library then how can i detect that user hasnt malloc suffecient memory.

Comment: Note: in C you should not cast the result of malloc() - you have to do this in C++ but it is redundant and potentially dangerous in C.

Comment: Another note: quite aside from the fluke that writing past the end of the buffer, you have another fluke that `printf` and `strlen` have found a 0 byte after the `l`, but you had no right to expect that either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sometimes happens to work but it's definitely not safe on any system. You are writing past the end of what `malloc` is giving you. From the viewpoint of C it's illegal, but from the viewpoint of the OS it might be ok (that memory might be paged with adequate permissions).

Another problem is that if you later call `malloc` again, it might give you some memory including those 5 bytes that you are using without asking. This should provide some [interesting debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unusual_software_bug) sessions.

> here i have just allocated only 5 bytes to destination then still why
>   destination length is 10.?

The destination has only `5` bytes allocated, but because of the way malloc works on your system, this doesn't cause an invalid write, since it happens to be inside a valid page.

> where other bytes are stored.?

Right after the first 5, for now.

> Is it safe in embedded system.? any chances to crash or segmention
>   fault.?

**It's unsafe in any system**. Many chances of crashes.

> how can i detect this type of mistakes.?

Using valgrind or any memory debugger. A gentle introduction to valgrind can be found [here.](http://valgrind.org/gallery/linux_mag.html)

¹ 
<sub>For example, on Linux (Glibc), small (~64 bytes) `malloc` requests are served from a small list of preallocated pages called "fastbins". Each fastbin has a fixed size, and hence using an allocated fastbin up to that size would not trigger a segmentation violation. More details on how this happens can be found [here,](http://bardofschool.blogspot.com/2009/09/glibc-malloc-implementation.html) for a more rigorous treatment of the topic you might refer to [the malloc source code.](http://www.eglibc.org/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/trunk/libc/malloc/malloc.c?rev=13698&view=auto)</sub>

Comment: see i am writing one library where user asks for needed memory and library says allocate 10 bytes & then user malloc 10 bytes & pass its pointer to library. now library store some data there...now see if library said to allocate 10 bytes but user has allocated only 5 bytes & give that pointer to library then how can i detect that user hasnt malloc  suffecient memory.?

Comment: @Mr.32 You can't. This is C, so shooting themselves in the foot is a basic right of the users. Alternatively you culd take the gun away from them and allocate the memory yourself.

Comment: Just to reiterate and emphasize, even if it doesn't crash 999,999 times in a million, it is still by definition pure luck, and a change in the compiler, the OS, or the libraries could change the position of your stars any day.

Answer (score 5):

***Here i have just allocated only 5 bytes to destination then still why destination length is 10?***

```
printf("%s and size is %d",destination,strlen(destination));
```

The `strlen()` considers `\0` as the end of the string, So it continues counting until it enounters a `\0`. This does not mean `destination` has that much memory allocated.

You are writing beyond the bounds of the allocated memory and luckily it does not crash, but sure is an **Undefined Behavior** to do so. An Undefined Behavior means anything can happen & the behavior cannot be explained, luckily Your program does not crash.

***where other bytes are stored?***
The other bytes overwrite some other memory allocation beyond the 5 bytes allocated to `destination`.

***Is it safe in embedded system? any chances to crash or segmention fault?***
It is **NOT** safe. It causes an **Undefined Behavior** and If you are lucky that it works.

***how can i detect this type of mistakes?***
Each platform has certain **Memory profiling** tools like **Valgrind** for Linux/Unix, You can use them and they will point out such memory overrites.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not safe - writing beyond the end of an allocated block will typically cause heap corruption.

Use tools such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to catch this and other kinds of error.

Answer (score 0):

You are luck that it has not crashed. The third parameter of memcpy should be 4 and then you should put the null character in the 5 position to terminate the string.